# MySQL 150: Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, mysql-error-150

When I import the file to phpmyadmin I'm getting this err :

> #1005 - Can't create table `test_db`.`part_order` (errno: 150
>   "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")

I checked the syntax many times but I can't see what's wrong. I tried to use `INDEX` and `CONSTRAINT` but no success. Any help will be appreciated.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `all_products` (   
  `product_id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,   
  `product_name` VARCHAR(100)  NOT NULL,  
  `product_price` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,   
  `product_description` VARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL,  
  PRIMARY KEY(`product_id`, `product_name`)   
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=UTF8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `product_color` (   
  `color_id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,   
  `product_id` INT(10) NOT NULL,   
  `color_name` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,   
  PRIMARY KEY(`color_id`, `color_name`),   
  FOREIGN KEY(`product_id`) REFERENCES all_products(`product_id`)   
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=UTF8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (   
  `user_id` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,   
  `first_name` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,   
  `last_name` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,   
  `email` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,   
  `password` VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,   
  `address` VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,   
  `city` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,   
  `post_code` VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL,   
  PRIMARY KEY(`user_id`)   
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=UTF8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `part_order` (   
  `order_number` INT(10) NOT NULL ,   
  `product_name` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,   
  `color_name` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,   
  `qty` INT(10) NOT NULL,   
  PRIMARY KEY(`order_number`),   
  INDEX(`order_number`),   
  CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY(`product_name`) REFERENCES
    all_products(`product_name`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,   
  CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY(`color_name`) REFERENCES
    product_color(`color_name`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE   
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=UTF8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `orders` (   
  `order_number` INT(10) NOT NULL,   
  `user_id` INT(10) NOT NULL,   
  Date DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,   
  `total_cost` INT(10) NOT NULL,   
  `status` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,   
  PRIMARY KEY(`status`),   
  CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY(`order_number`) REFERENCES
    part_order(`order_number`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY(`user_id`) REFERENCES
    users(`user_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL requires indexes on the referenced columns (`product_name` and `color_name`). Add `INDEX(product_name)` to the `all_products` table and `INDEX(color_name)` to the `product_color` table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `all_products` (   
  `product_id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,   
  `product_name` VARCHAR(100)  NOT NULL,  
  `product_price` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,   
  `product_description` VARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL,  
  PRIMARY KEY(`product_id`, `product_name`),
  INDEX(`product_name`)   
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=UTF8;
```

From the [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html):

> MySQL requires indexes on foreign keys and referenced keys so that
>   foreign key checks can be fast and not require a table scan. In the
>   referencing table, there must be an index where the foreign key
>   columns are listed as the first columns in the same order. Such an
>   index is created on the referencing table automatically if it does not
>   exist. This index might be silently dropped later, if you create
>   another index that can be used to enforce the foreign key constraint.
>   index_name, if given, is used as described previously.